# Wait until data is downloaded from Firebase Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on one of my application where I am saving user subscription data in Firebase. Whenever the user starts using my application and the first page loads, I want to retrieve the user's subscription information and want to fetch subscription expiry date.

Now, as data is retrieved slowly, I do not understand, how can I wait for it and then my application shows first page. In `viewWillAppear`, I am calling this function:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [self retrieveChildData];

    });

//Here I also tried to call it on main thread. 

//[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(retrieveChildData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

-(void)retrieveChildData
{

    NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://Address.."];

    FIRDatabaseReference *ref = [[FIRDatabase database] referenceFromURL:strUrl];

    [ref observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

        for ( FIRDataSnapshot *child in snapshot.children) {

            userSubsData = child.value; //or craft an object instead of dict

            }
    }];

}
```

`userSubsData` is NSDictionary and I also know how to check if it is empty or if it retrieved any info. But it still, the problem is how to wait for it and then load the page.

Comment: so you are asking how to execute a task in background thread and then call the completion block when task finished?

Comment: Yes, because I want to use those values in viewDidLoad.

Comment: basically, the workflow would be like this: `viewDidLoad` (main) -> call `retrieveChildData` (main) -> update `userSubsData` property inside firebase block (background) -> update the UI related to `userSubsData` model (main). `viewDidLoad` should never wait until the data is retrieved... so the UI update should be executed inside the firebase completion callback...

Comment: It's same either we call it in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear but I understand your point. Instead of using "retrieveChildData" method and calling it in background thread, I can call Firebase completion block directly in viewDidLoad. I think, this trick will work. Will update you soon. Thanks.

Comment: Firebase completion block also runs in background and if I put that in viewDidLoad, it does not wait for it to complete.

Comment: yes, viewDidLoad will not wait for it. why u need to wait for it until it finished? you can assign blank values to the UI for your firebase data field or showing a HUD view to indicate loading in progress, and then update the UI with latest firebase data when the task is done...

Comment: Because I need to check user subscription expiry date. If user's subscription expired, then I need to deactivate some features.

Comment: then the most appropriate way is showing a loading HUD (maybe `MBProgressHUD`) when task is in progress, and remove the HUD when task is done... when data is loading, the user will not be able to tap any button because of the existence of  HUD... you can't block the `viewDidLoad` function I think...

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.

Answer (score -1):

A very simple trick works with NSTimer. I just called timer function in viewDidLoad.

```
 statusTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0f
                                                   target:self selector:@selector(checkStatus:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

In checkStatus, I am checking if data is retrieved or not and then invalidate the timer.

```
-(void)checkStatus:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    NSLog(@"Timer started");

    if([userSubsInfo count] != 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Subscription data retrived");
        [statusTimer invalidate];
        statusTimer = nil;

    }
}
```